# Not able to make a POST call using postman

Tags: postman

I got 403 forbidden response when try to make a post call from postman. But it is working for get call. Please help.

[Get call working fine[When try to make Post call, it is failing with 403 status code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW8MQ.png)

[But Post call is working fine with browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vwZS.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: post and get are very different and they are not supposed to give you the same result